# How can I reproduce akka quarantie situation?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

Dealing with akka cluster sometimes I get quarantine situation with such exception:

```
2016-03-22 10:01:37.090UTC WARN [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] Remoting - Association to [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@10.10.80.26:2551] having UID [1417400423] is irrecoverably failed. UID is now quarantined and all messages to this UID will be delivered to dead letters. Remote actorsystem must be restarted to recover from this situation.
```

The problem is that I can't reproduce it!
I just can't write any simple code snippet which provoces quarantine event.

How is there any simple way to provoce quarantine event?

Answer (score 0):

Just start two seed nodes and stop the network of one of the seed node, you will see this issue.
I have reproduced this issue. I created multiple VMs to form a cluster and stopped network from one of the VM.